# Keep Getting ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

As the title says I keep getting this error and don't know what I'm missing. I've cleaned the project several times. Here is my code:

```
 startActivity(new Intent(this, UsrPrefs.class));
```

In the manifest:

```
<application

    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".IcyArmActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".UserPreferences"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PREFS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!!!!!  Thanks you guys. I thought the UsrPrefs.class was the name of the class so that is what I was using. I see the connection now. DOH!!!!

Comment: Please do not edit your question to thank others -- instead, _accept_ their answer (the check mark next to the answer, and possibly an upvote as well for other answers that help you) and leave a _comment_ with your thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you defined a class as an activity with one name and starting the other activity which is not registered with that name in the `manifest.xml`

Replace this:

```
<activity 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".UserPreferences"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PREFS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

with

```
<activity 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".UsrPrefs"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PREFS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your menifest the name of activity is **UserPreferences**.So edit like this

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, UserPreferences.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
startActivity(new Intent(IcyArmActivity.this, UserPreferences.class));
```

for starting new Activity from main Activity because you have declared UsrPrefs as UserPreferences in manifest

**OR**

you can   declare `UsrPrefs` as new Activity  in manifest as :

```
<activity android:name=".UsrPrefs" />
```